# Insert Data in Oracle DB using PHP

Tags: php, oracle, prepared-statement, oracle-call-interface

Inserting data in oracle DB using `oci_8`. Sample query to insert string with special characters or quotes

```
 update TABLENAME set COMMENTS = 'As per Mark's email dated 28-Feb-2015 - Bill Gates & Team's effort' where ID = 99;
```

To insert/update

```
$query = 'update TABLENAME set COMMENTS = '$_POST[comments]';

$result = customexecute($new_query);

public function customexecute($query)
{

    $resutlt = parent::customquery($query);
    return $resutlt;
}


public static function customquery($query)
{

  try{

        $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $query);
        oci_execute($stmt,OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
        oci_commit(db_singleton::getInstance());
        oci_free_statement($stmt);
        }catch (Exception  $e)
        {
            print_r($e);
        }

    }
```

Executing it on ORACLE DB it says `SQl command not properly ended.` Looked into `Parameterized queries` mentioned [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) but not able to integrate it succesfully.

```
$query = 'UPDATE tablename SET field = :field WHERE id = :id';
$stmt = oci_parse($oracleConnection, $query);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':field', "The field value with 'apostrophes' and so");
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':id', '125');
$result = oci_execute($stmt);
```

I can pass `:bind_comments` in my query which is in my controller. But `$stmt` resides in my **db_singleton** file (general for all DB queries) and can not pass seperately for a individual query.

**How can I sanitize user input or do not allow data to be used in creating SQL code**

Comment: Can you post a complete snippet please? I'm missing the code that creates the SQL string (`$query`) and the binding part.

Comment: @Mureinik check the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the update function, pass everything needed to the execute function:

```
$result = customExecute(
    'update xxx set comments=:COMMENTS where id=:ID',
    [
        ':COMMENTS' => $_POST['comment'],
        ':ID' => 99
    ]
);
```

Then in the execute function simply iterate the array to bind all params:

```
public static function customExecute($sql, array $params = [])
{
    $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
    foreach ($params as $key => &$value) {
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, $key, $value);
    }
    $result = oci_execute($stmt);
    ...
}
```

Comment: timclutton: `$result = oci_execute($stmt);echo $result;`. The output is 1

Comment: Yes, because the return value from [`oci_execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php#refsect1-function.oci-execute-returnvalues) is `bool`.  What do you expect `$result` to contain?

Comment: Agree, but what if am getting some value from stored procedure which needs to be bind with output parameter. How can I bind a PHP variable as output from a stored procedure variable and return that value ?

Comment: In that case you would need different handling; a function that knows it's getting output values set by `oci_bind_by_name`. But now you are asking a different question from your original one. Read [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-sps-095636.html) for information on calling stored procedures from PHP (there is an example of binding output params, which is actually just the same as binding input params).

Comment: executing your solution the query generated is `Update TABLENAME set COMMENTS = :COMMENT WHERE ID =:ID;`. Further when executing it in SQL developer,it says `invalid host/bind variable name`

Comment: timclutton:`COMMENT` is a `reserved` word in Oracle. Changing it to `MYCOMMENTS` works though. Also if I have only one variable to bind, do I need to loop or just use `oci_bind_by_name($stmt,":MYCOMMENTS",$comments);` ?

Comment: Ah, of course - I'll change my answer to avoid confusion.  You can use the same loop method for 1 or more variables (even for none!).

Comment: the loop works fine with 1 or more variables. Could you explain the case for `none` ?

Comment: If there are no params in the query (e.g. `select * from dual`) then passing an empty `array` will cause the loop not to execute and nothing to bind.  Even better would be to make the parameter optional (`function customExecute($sql, $params = [])`); then you can omit the param from the call.

Comment: Upvoted and accepted. And the one i was curious about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002992/php-oci-call-stored-procedure-with-parameters

Answer (score 0):

No, unsurprisingly, MySQL functions won't work with Oracle DB :)

You need to parameterise things, e.g.:

```
$query = 'update TABLENAME set COMMENTS = :bind_comments where id = :bind_id';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':bind_comments', $_POST['comments']);
$stmt->bindParam(':bind_id', $_POST['id']);

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I can pass `:bind_comments` in my query which is in controller. But `$stmt` resides in my `db_singleton` file (general for DB queries) and can not pass seperately for a individual query.

Comment: You don't need to pass the $stmt from your singleton. The statement is generated every time you prepare a query (the `$dbh->prepare($query);` line). All you need is to access the `$dbh` (database handler) from your code. Anyway, this code is using PDO, and the Oracle PDO drives isn't the reccomended way to access an Oracle DB (It's marked as experimental: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php)

Comment: Agreed. As others have said, I would use OCI rather than PDO for Oracle. Use an array if you need to pass in multiple bind parameters & their values

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of using the OCI8 PHP extensions is:

```
$query = 'UPDATE tablename SET field = :field WHERE id = :id';
$stmt = oci_parse($oracleConnection, $query);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':field', "The field value with 'apostrophes' and so");
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':id', '125');
$result = oci_execute($stmt);
```

More information: http://php.net/manual/book.oci8.php

Comment: mHouses: The correct way is mentioned in manual but how can I modify according to above code structure ?