# PHP-OCI Call Stored Procedure with parameters

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-call-interface

**Stored Procedure:**

```
parentchildhrs number(7,0);
childhours number(7,0);

begin

COMBINED_HOURS(122,parentchildhrs,childhours);

end;
```

The above when executed via `Oracle SQL Developer` outputs the correct expected value which are hours. Output below

```
CHILD HOURS 50
parent task id 122
parentchild HOURS 100
```

Now when I call with PHP-OCI, it outputs nothing.

```
$taskID = 122;
$parent_hours = '';
$child_hours = '';
$procedure = "BEGIN TASK_COMBINED_CHILD_HRS(:task_id, :parent_child_hours, :child_hours); END;";
$test = $taskmaster->getHours($procedure, [':task_id' => $taskID,':parent_child_hours' => (int)$sum_parent_child_hours,':child_hours' => (int)$sum_child_hours]);



    public function getHours($query, $params){
           $result_hours = parent::ocibindbyname($query, $params);
           return $result_hours;
    }

public static function customquery($query, $params)
{

  try{  

      $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $query);
      foreach ($params as $key => &$value) {              
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, $key, $value, 32);
      }
      oci_execute($stmt,OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
      oci_commit($conn);
      oci_free_statement($stmt);
      return $params;
      }catch (Exception  $e){
        print_r($e);
    }               
}
```

Printing the result gives

```
Array
(
    [:task_id] => 1142
    [:parent_child_hours] => 100
    [:child_hours] => 50
)
```

1. How can I bind a PHP variable for  `parent_child_hours` and `child_hours` as output from a stored procedure variable ?

Comment: binding pl/sql output variables is also done with [oci_bind_by_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php). See example 10.

Comment: @winkbrace binding is working, but how can I get the output of those variables ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `foreach` approach from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29005729/3775731) to another of your questions is not a good idea when dealing with stored procedures.

While it does work (as shown in your question, the variables are set in the `$params` array after execution) the biggest issue is that you must provide the fourth parameter (`maxlength`) to `oci_bind_by_name`.  You've used a static value of `32` in your code, but an error is raised when the length of a value exceeds this.  It can't be calculated at runtime and setting it to a very large value is inefficient (maybe this isn't a problem for your application).

Since you are running a known stored procedure, you should know the `maxlength` of output values at design-time and these can statically entered by putting all the `oci_*` functions in `getHours()`, instead of trying to abstract all calls to `customExecute()`.